# How to publish a TYPO3 6.1 extension to TER?

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 6.1.1 (actual stable) it seems, what the interfaces changed and upload options are dissappeared in the Extension Manager.

So, how should we upload an extension for TYPO3 6.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [extension_uploader](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_uploader) now. The extension manager itself does not contain developer features anymore.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I'm almostly amazed, what there is no official documentation about it.

Comment: Update : Since December 2020, please see https://typo3.org/article/a-new-way-to-manage-your-extensions-in-the-ter

Answer (score 1):

Since 2020, there have been some changes: There is a REST API for managing extensions in TER. Please see the following resources:

- [REST API for extensions.typo3.org](https://extensions.typo3.org/faq)
- typo3.org news: [A new way to manage extensions in the TER](https://typo3.org/article/a-new-way-to-manage-your-extensions-in-the-ter)

You can now work with API keys so you do not have to pass your credentials when using the API.

There is a CLI tool called ["tailor"](https://github.com/TYPO3/tailor) to make it easier to use the API with your extension.